# pass pointer array to function and count size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code, i'm trying to pass array in function so i can extend the array. but i'm stuck at how to get length of array.

I have tried many and this code as well. Please guide

**Edit** How can i change size of poniter array from default 4 to `size+1`, i tried `malloc` but didn't understood correctly and it didn't worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>

struct Item {
    int item;
    double value;
};

void addItem(Item *arrPtr, int &size, int &count, int item, double value)
{
    ++size;
    arrPtr = (Item *)malloc(size*sizeof(arrPtr));
    arrPtr[count++].item = item;
    arrPtr[count++].value = value;
}

int main(void){

    int size = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Item arrPtr[size];

    addItem(arrPtr, size, count, 1, 239.99);
    addItem(arrPtr, size, count, 2, 129.75);
    addItem(arrPtr, size, count, 3, 99.95);
    addItem(arrPtr, size, count, 4, 350.89);    

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %f \n", arrPtr[i].item, arrPtr[i].value);
        printf("%d, %f", arrPtr[i].item, arrPtr[i].value);
    }

    //printf("%d, %f \n", arrPtr[0].item, arrPtr[0].value);
    //printf("%d, %f", arrPtr[1].item, arrPtr[1].value);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot extend an array that has already been statically created. At the moment, when you are adding an item, you are creating an entirely different array and adding one item to it! Let alone getting how long the array is. Try looking up a C alternative to the C++ std::vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct ItemLabel {  // made it a typedef (type definition)
    int item;               // replaced Item with ItemLabel
    double value;
} Item;                     // called my new type Item

void addItem( Item ** arrPtr, int * size, int * count, int item, double value )
// Receiving the pointers for size and count, to achieve what you want to achieve

{
    ++( *size );

    // getting the size of the element, instead of the pointer...
    // using realloc instead to expand the size, as you seem to want
    *arrPtr = realloc( *arrPtr, ( * size ) * sizeof( ** arrPtr ) );
    // also no typecasting voidPtr

    (*arrPtr)[*count].item = item;
    (*arrPtr)[*count].value = value;
    ( *count )++;
    // incrementing count twice, would increment the count twice
    // I don't think you would want that...
}

int main( ){    // removed the void argument

    int size = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Item * arrPtr = NULL;

    // sending addresses of size & count, so that they will actually get increased
    // also the arrPtr, so that the pointer will also get actually modified
    addItem( &arrPtr, &size, &count, 1, 239.99 );
    addItem( &arrPtr, &size, &count, 2, 129.75 );
    addItem( &arrPtr, &size, &count, 3, 99.95 );
    addItem( &arrPtr, &size, &count, 4, 350.89 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d, %f\n", arrPtr[i].item, arrPtr[i].value );
        // removed the second printf, put it back if you want...
    }

    //printf("%d, %f \n", arrPtr[0].item, arrPtr[0].value);
    //printf("%d, %f", arrPtr[1].item, arrPtr[1].value);

    // your function ends anyway, but it's never bad to free
    free( arrPtr );
    getch( );
    return 0;
}
```

You can find bunch of comments in the code above. It does what I think you'd want it to do on my end. To be exact, this doesn't actually work on my end, because I use MSVC on Windows, so [I cannot use `getch( );`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235446.aspx); so to make it work I just replace it with `_getch( );`.

Changes mostly involve sending the addresses of the variables which you want to ***really*** change, and arguments list of the `addItem` function to have `*`s.

`typedef` part is also important, it allows you to refer the type with simple `Item` as seem to want; else you'd have to refer it as `struct ItemLabel {blabla}`, long stuff...

I didn't change it, but I would recommend using only the `size`, instead of each the `size` and `count` **and** `int item` of the function, simply because they almost always carry the same value. In that case you'd have to change the `.item` and `.value` assignments as following:

```
    (*arrPtr)[*size - 1].item = *size;
    (*arrPtr)[*size - 1].value = value;
```

Feel free to ask away any further confusion you may have...

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort i like it and i solve my problem.  But, not typecasting voidPtr gave me error on `reallocate()` so i caste it to `item` and it worked.

Comment: @Munsaf You are all welcome. I can understand the error that occurs when you don't typecast the `realloc`, my old Visual Studio 2012 also used to do that, hopefully the Visual Studio Express 2013 doesn't give that error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

C pointers don't record the length of the array pointed at. Pass size in explicitly, or establish a convention where a particular value marks the logical end of the array (which is why C strings end with the null character), or build a struct which carries both the array pointer and a length field and pass that around.

Answer (score 0):

```
Item arrPtr[size];
```

this variable length arrays, it can not be used unless the compiler of C99 or later.

```
arrPtr = (Item *)malloc(size*sizeof(arrPtr));
```

You do not change the original, even after this set as a pointer when you pass an array as a pointer, since the copy it.

Do the following as one way from the above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct Item {
    int item;
    double value;
} Item; //need typedef in C (not C++)

Item *addItem(Item *arrPtr, int *size, int *count, int item, double value){
    ++*size;
    arrPtr = (Item *)realloc(arrPtr, (*size)*sizeof(*arrPtr));//sizeof(Item), not sizeof(Item*)
    arrPtr[*count].item    = item;//count : The count too if you count up here
    arrPtr[(*count)++].value = value;
    return arrPtr;//return a pointer that has changed
}

int main(void){
    Item *arrPtr=NULL;//use it as a pointer
    int size  = 0;//Capacity
    int count = 0;//The number of data that is actually stored
    int i;

    //&size, &count : Can not be used reference in C(not C++, You are using the C++ probably)
    arrPtr = addItem(arrPtr, &size, &count, 1, 239.99);
    arrPtr = addItem(arrPtr, &size, &count, 2, 129.75);
    arrPtr = addItem(arrPtr, &size, &count, 3, 99.95);
    arrPtr = addItem(arrPtr, &size, &count, 4, 350.89);    

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){//int i : C99 syntax
        printf("%d, %f \n", arrPtr[i].item, arrPtr[i].value);
//      printf("%d, %f", arrPtr[i].item, arrPtr[i].value);//Duplicate
    }
    free(arrPtr);//release
    getch();//not portable
    return 0;
}
```